# Критичесские секции в ansible

Tags: ansible

Подскажите, есть задача которая не может выполняться параллельно для нескольких хостов. своего рода критическая секция. можно ли сделать так, чтоб при любых раскладах запускалась только один инстанс задачи ?

Comment: [run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) для разового запуска + [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) для указания хоста. Оно?

Comment: Не оно. Мне не надо ограничивать количество запусков. Мне надо ограничит количество одновременных запусков.

Comment: [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)

Comment: @UserName , отлично, то что нужно. спасибо.